# Tarjan algorithm based on BFS

Tags: breadth-first-search

I have an implemented BFS algorithm and I want to find SCC with Tarjan's algorithm using my BFS (implemented with colors and time method). Here is the code:        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    void dfs_visit_color(int v, Graf *G, int *time)
    {
        time++;
        G->d[v] = *time;
        G->color[v] = GRI;
        NodeT *p = G->t[v];
        int w;
        printf("%d ", v);
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            w = p->val;
            if (G->color[w] == ALB)
            {
                T[w] = v;
                dfs_visit_color(w, G, time);
            }
            p = p->next;
        }
        G->color[v] = NEGRU;
        time++;
        G->f[v] = *time;
    }



   void dfs_color(Graf *G){
int time = 0, i;

for (i = 0; i < G->n; i++)
{
    if (G->color[i] = ALB);
}

for (i = 0; i < G->n; i++)
{
    if (G->color[i] == ALB)
    {
        dfs_visit_color(i, G, &time);
    }
}
```

}